# Connecting to database dynamically with table adapters

Tags: c#, ado.net, tableadapter

I have an application which creates table adapters using a dataset at design time. This is tied to a specific database. My requirement is, I want to be able to connect to a different database which has the same schema as the previous one. I should be able to achieve this at runtime. Is there anyway I could do it ? Or what is the best alternate way using TableAdapters ?

Cheers,
Harish

Comment: Yes you could do it. Look at `app.config` for connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change the database your adapters point to by simply closing the existing connection, changing the connection string, then opening the new connection.

```
//Work with existing connection...

tableAdapter1.Connection.Close();
tableAdapter1.Connection.ConnectionString = "Your new DB connection string";
tableAdapter1.Connection.Open();

//Work with same adapter but now pointing to new DB specified in above string.
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt :). That was pretty nice and simple.